# Is it possible to merge two stack overflow accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I created this account several years ago, but apparently forgot I'd created it a half year or so later and created another account.  Is it possible to merge the non-primary account with my primary account so I can migrate ownership / tracking of the question that I asked with it?

I know it seems kind of one-offish, but it's just something I thought may be possible that would be convenient to do.  Obviously this isn't a big deal if it isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it's both possible and done, enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting it to be some method of authenticating by adding the same OpenID to both accounts and somehow merging from there. Admin intervention is so much easier. :D